# How can I get form dynamic input data with React Js?

Tags: forms, reactjs

So I have a `ItemForm`. In this form, there are dynamic input fields called `name`. The reason why it is dynamic is that if there are three languages used by an user, such as English, Russian and Chinese, there will be three input fields for `name` with each language type `English Name`, `Russian Name`, `Chinese Name`.

To do that, in the `ItemForm`, I made code like below.
 `const itemLanguages = product.languages.map((language) => {
      return <input key={language.id} ref={language.name} id={language.id} placeholder={language.name + ' Name'} type="text" required="true" />
    })`

Generating dynamic input fields depending on `languages` is working fine. However, I have a problem of how to get input data. Since I use `ref` to get data of input field, unless I specify all types of language, I cannot get data of these input fields...

How can I get data from dynamic input fields without specifying all types of language?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make these [controlled inputs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), they can fire an `onChange` callback which updates the component's `state`.  That way, the data will be available without having to inspect the DOM.

**Note** - you will also need to set the `value` attribute of the inputs to the value from `state` otherwise the user won't be able to enter any text.

For example:

```
const itemLanguages = product.languages.map((language) => {
  return <input
    key={language.id}
    placeholder={language.name + ' Name'}
    type="text"
    required="true"
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, language.name)}
    value={this.state[language.name]} />
})
```

where the handler is given by something like:

```
onChange (languageName, evt) {
  this.setState({ [languageName]: evt.target.value })
}
```

This may need to be nuanced slightly depending on the way your component uses its `state`, but I hope that demonstrates the principle.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!